# https to http change url through .htaccess in magento sites except checkout or my account page

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ssl, https

My requirement is all https url open on http and check out and my account page always open on https.
i try on this code but not solve

```
RewriteEngine on
# From https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checkout/multishipping/login/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wishlist/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# From http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/cart/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/account/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/multishipping/login/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wishlist/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help me

Comment: your first rule is commented in most parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code for solved this problem

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(shop|blog|stockists|inthepress|contacts|review|home) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below and which is working for me  in one of my sites.

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^index.php/onepagecheckout/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/onepagecheckout 
[R,L]

   # RewriteRule ^index.php/yourpageurl/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/yourpageurl
[R,L]
```

hope you can understand and it could useful to you.

Comment: thanks for reply. my requrement is i try to hits one url https://www.example.com/ its change to http://www.example.com